# No Output Displayed when i run and echo lsof in cgi - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cgi, port, pid, lsof

I have recently started using cgi. As I have to display port usage information about certain ports, I had written the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>PortInfo</title></head><body><center>"
echo "<h1>Port 80 Usage Info</h1>"

#method1
echo "<pre> $(lsof -i :80) </pre>"

#method2
echo "$(lsof -i :80 > /home/shine/Desktop/tmp.txt)"
echo "<pre> $(cat /home/shine/Desktop/tmp.txt) </pre>" 

echo "<center>Information generated on $(date)</center>"
echo "</center></body></html>"
```

Method 1:
The problem over here is that the `echo "<pre> $(lsof -i :80) </pre>"` does not give any output.

Method 2:
In this method `echo "$(lsof -i :80 > /home/shine/Desktop/tmp.txt)"` never creates a file named tmp.txt on the desktop, as it is supposed to do.

Important Note:
Both the methods specified above run perfectly once they are executed in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I kind of found the answer I was searching for, more like an alternative.

Somebody mentioned somewhere, something about cron scripts so, I did the following.

**Step I**:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Enter `2` for nano editor

Add the following lines:

```
* * * * * lsof -i :80 > /home/shine/port80.txt
* * * * * lsof -i :3000 > /home/shine/port3000.txt
```

Note:The above lines of code will generate two text files containing port 80 & 3000 info
in the current users' home directory every minute.

`ctrl+o`, `enter`, `ctrl+x` to save and exit.

**Step II**:

In apache's www directory
Create a php file with the following code.

```
<?php

$output80 = shell_exec("cat '/home/shine/reports/port80.txt'");
echo "<pre>$output80</pre>";
$output3000 = shell_exec('cat "/home/shine/reports/port3000.txt"');
echo "<pre>$output3000</pre>";

?>
```

This is the only way I can think of at this moment to make lsof work on a web page.